# Game programming deltatime

Tags: java, graphics, delta

Okay so I understand the importance of using deltaTime for frame independent animation. However, fps isn't always constant, but rather it changes frequently(atleast on pcs). So if it changes that means your deltaTime variable will always be changing(e.g. 1/60 to 1/59). So lets say for one second your deltaTime is 1/60 and you update all your values according to that. But if for the next second the fps is changed to 59 or 58, then your deltaTime will still be updating according to 1/60 and it will be inconsistent. How do you solve this problem? You never know the fps of the next second(cant see into the future)..

Comment: That's exactly why you measure the delta time, so your physics engine can use the real time slice and not the ideal time slice.

Comment: I think you're confusing the delta-time with FPS.  The intention of the delta-time is to average out the time between updates so as to maintain the FPS at a steady rate.  That is, the delta-time is variable and will constantly change between updates, but the FPS should be (as much as possible) constant. Don't see a single update a indication of the frame rate.  Until you've done a complete second worth of updates, you won't know the frame rate...

Comment: I know that you can't know the fps until a full seconds worth of updates, which is why I asked this question in the first place.. If for one whole second, you have one fps, but then in the NEXT SECOND, the fps changes because for example more data is being processed, then how do you know what the delta time is going to be beforehand? You calculate delta time from the fps.. but if you don't know the fps of the next whole SECOND, how do you get it right?

Comment: In the scenario I described, you would be still be dealing with the previous second's deltaTime, not the current one.. which would change the animation.